# ubuntu wireless signal low on my pc

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-router, signal-strength

I have 2 computers both with Ubuntu. With both of them I connect to a WIFI router.

The problem is that with one of them the wifi signal seems to be lower, i.e. it looks like the receiver of one computer is not as good as the other.

As a consequence this computer disconnects quite often because of low signal even if this is not the case, the other computer

I would like to visualize a value indicating the signal strength received on both PCs.

How to do?

Answer (score 0):

On the Ubuntu desktop there is usually a gauge icon in the top right corner, roughly indicating the wireless signal strength. [To watch this value live:](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/06/display-wifi-signal-strength-in-real.html)

```
watch -n 1 "awk 'NR==3 {print \"WiFi Signal Strength = \" \$3 \"00 %\"}''' /proc/net/wireless"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing an issue where the wifi signal was available near the modem. But a few commands in the terminal solved the issue.
Follow instruction in this link :[to solve wifi issue- instructions](http://www.coderew.com/tech/how-to-solve-rtl-wifi-issues-ubuntu/)

That would solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.